# Float validation on Rails

Tags: ruby, validation

Im trying to add validation that prevents a user from entering more than 6 digits before the decimal place, and only 3 after the decimal place. I have precision set up at 8 with a scale of 2, however it is producing an error page. I just want to stop user's from entering anything more than the format set. I have max length already set to 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your precision and scale are off. Based on your description it should be (9,3) rather than (8,2).

Then the following should work:

```
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  validates :my_float, numericality: {less_than: 1_000_000.0, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.001}
end
```

This will validate that the number is less than 1 Million (6 digits to the left of the decimal) and greater than or equal to 0.001 three digits to the right of the decimal. If you need to handle negative numbers this could get a bit more interesting.

You could also possibly go with something like:

```
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  validates :my_float, format: { with: /-?\d{1,6}\.\d{1,3}/}
end
```

Validate optional negative followed by 1-6 digits followed by a period followed by 1-3 digits.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the precision and scale problem. Gave that a try and it works perfect! Edit - That second format you shown is definitely more suitable for the application I am working with. Thanks again!

Comment: The first example doesn't limit the number of fractional digits, e.g. 0.0012345 would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Stefan from my understanding rails will round this (cast it) during persistence so yes you are correct it will not "limit" the value the but application will handle it without error.

Comment: But without a validation error, it won't prevent the user from entering such values, as requested by the OP. Maybe I'm too picky :-)